# How to convert DB date into local date in Rails

Tags: datetime, ruby-on-rails-4, timestamp, timezone-offset

In `rails 4`, i try to convert database date into local date time but not display it proper.

```
Date get from DB: 2015-09-24T04:44:12.020Z
```

I used below syntax:

```
DateTime.parse(visitor.attributes.signOut).to_time.localtime
```

Its display proper in `IST` but not display proper in UTC. Display `UTC-4` but user see in `UTC-5` so DB datetime must be convert into `UTC-5 instead of UTC-4.`

How to `manage` different `timezone` like above in Rails. Any one have solution or idea.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For saving time in local timezone to database this has to be set in application.rb

```
config.time_zone = 'UTC'
```

Try this

Comment: Actually i don't want to save local time... but want to display time in local

Comment: I dont want to display only UTC but local time means user open in any country then display DB datetime into local datetime. Make Sense?